# Draw rectangle with mouse while maintaining a given ratio

Tags: vb.net, graphics

I have what I think is a basic problem that has me scratching my head.

I want to be able to draw a rectangle on my form while constraining it to a given ratio. Similar to how Photoshop's crop tool works.

I can scale images correctly using a ratio, but I am having trouble applying the formula to a 'live' drawn rectangle.

Here is the basic working code to draw said rectangle.

```
Public Class Form2

Dim mRect As Rectangle

Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseDown(ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
mRect = New Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 0, 0)
Me.Invalidate()
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseMove(ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
mRect = New Rectangle(mRect.Left, mRect.Top, e.X - mRect.Left, e.Y - mRect.Top)
Me.Invalidate()
End If
End sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
Using pen As New Pen(Color.Red, 3)
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, mRect)
End Using

End class
```

The above code works fine to draw a freeform rectangle. I'm just not sure where or how to apply the formula to ensure the drawn rectangle always adheres to a given ratio such as 1.5

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *a given ratio*? Do you mean that the height and width of the rectangle must always be a multiple of 1.5?

Comment: Sorry no I didn't make that clear, the 1.5 was an example. The ratio will be calculated before scaling the rectangle. Like Photoshop's crop tool, if I give it dimensions of 320x200 I can scale that rectangle up or down keeping that ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ;

```
 Dim mRect As Rectangle

 Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseDown(ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
     mRect = New Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 0, 0)
     Me.Invalidate()
 End Sub

 Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseMove(ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
     If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
         mRect = New Rectangle(mRect.Left, mRect.Top, e.X - mRect.Left, e.Y - mRect.Top)
         'Replace 1.5 with the scale you want to use
         Dim hgt As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(mRect.Height/1.5)
         Dim wdth As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(mRect.Width/1.5)
         mRect.Size = New Size(wdth*1.5, hgt*1.5)
         Me.Invalidate()
     End If
 End sub

 Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
     Using pen As New Pen(Color.Red, 3)
         e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, mRect)
     End Using
 End class
```

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate the response, however Scale doesn't appear to be a method of Rectangle unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @Floodlight sorry, that was for the `Rect` class in wpf.Updated.

Comment: Thank you for your help kind sir. I was able to find a solution :)